# How to get all values for a given key in a nested structure in clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(def threads
  {:values
   [{:_id "t1"
     :u {:uid 1}
     :members {:values [{:uid 1} {:uid 2}]}
     :messages {:values
                [{:_id "m1" :u {:uid 1}}
                 {:_id "m2" :u {:uid 2}}]}}
    {:_id "t2"
     :u {:uid 12}
     :members {:values [{:uid 11} {:uid 12}]}
     :messages {:values
                [{:_id "m3" :u {:uid 13}}
                 {:_id "m4" :u {:uid 12}}]}}]})
```

Need to find out all values for the key :uid
In this case answer should return [1 2 11 12 13] without using any global bindings. Needs solution scale for any level of nested structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done with tree-seq and filter, or with post-walk. Both appraoches are interesting to me:

tree-seq:

```
user> (map :uid 
           (filter #(if (and (map? %) (:uid %)) true  false)  
                   (tree-seq #(or (map? %) (vector? %)) identity threads)))
(1 2 1 1 2 13 12 12 11 12)
```

Which looks better when threaded out with `->>` (and with set and vec to remove dups)

```
user> (->> (tree-seq #(or (map? %) (vector? %)) identity threads) 
           (filter #(if (and (map? %) (:uid %)) true  false)) 
           (map :uid)  
           set 
           vec)                                
[1 2 11 12 13]
```

or with postwalk:

```
user> (let [results (atom [])]
        (clojure.walk/postwalk
           #(do (if-let [uid (:uid %)] (swap! results conj uid)) %)
           threads)
         @results)
[1 2 1 1 2 13 12 12 11 12]
```

This walks the structure with a function that, if the structure contains a key named :uid, appends it to a local atom. Then at the end return the accumulated contents of the atom. This differs slightly from your example because it accumulates duplicates. If you want to eliminate them efficiently then use a set as the accumulator instead of a vector, then turn it into a vector once at the end (your example has results in a vector)

```
user> (let [results (atom #{})] 
         (clojure.walk/postwalk 
            #(do (if-let [uid (:uid %)] (swap! results conj uid)) %) 
            threads) 
         (vec @results))
[1 2 11 12 13]
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur. I like the tree-seq answer more. As I have started using clojure - I like steps of data-in->data-out more than atom approaches. Learnt something new today - thanks a lot :)

Comment: `(map :uid (filter #(if (and (map? %) (:uid %)) true  false) coll))` could be replaced with just `(keep :uid coll)`.

Comment: ohhh, fancy :) I like the look of that much better.

Answer (score 4):

Using your data structure:

```
(def threads
  {:values
   [{:_id "t1"
     :u {:uid 1}
     :members {:values [{:uid 1} {:uid 2}]}
     :messages {:values
                [{:_id "m1" :u {:uid 1}}
                 {:_id "m2" :u {:uid 2}}]}}
    {:_id "t2"
     :u {:uid 12}
     :members {:values [{:uid 11} {:uid 12}]}
     :messages {:values
                [{:_id "m3" :u {:uid 13}}
                 {:_id "m4" :u {:uid 12}}]}}]})
```

Below is a more elegant way to extract all values for the key `:uid`.

Using [thread-last](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E), [tree-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep), and [keep](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep):

```
(->> threads
     (tree-seq coll? identity)
     (keep :uid))
```

Result: `(1 1 2 1 2 12 11 12 13 12)`

If you need only distinct values, add [distinct](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/distinct):

```
(->> threads
     (tree-seq coll? identity)
     (keep :uid)
     (distinct)) ; <-
```

Result: `(1 2 12 11 13)`

Need them sorted? Just add [sort](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort):

```
(->> threads
     (tree-seq coll? identity)
     (keep :uid)
     (distinct)
     (sort)) ; <-
```

Result: `(1 2 11 12 13)`

Need a vector? Add [vec](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec):

```
(->> threads
     (tree-seq coll? identity)
     (keep :uid)
     (distinct)
     (sort)
     (vec)) ; <-
```

Result: `[1 2 11 12 13]`

Lastly, you could create a function to give it a name:

```
(defn extract-vals-for-key [key collection]
  (->> collection
       (tree-seq coll? identity)
       (keep key)
       (distinct)
       (sort)
       (vec)))
```