# clojure prewalk with select-keys

Tags: clojure

```
(clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (map? %)
                           (select-keys  % [:c])
                            %)
                      {:a 1 :b [{:c 3} {:d 4}] :c 5})
=>{:c 5}
```

why does this only find `{:c 5}` and not also `{:c 3}`?
I'm trying to write something that will pull out all key/value pairs that exist for any form and at any level for the key I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it your function is called with

```
{:c 5, :b [{:c 3} {:d 4}], :a 1}
```

...it returns:

```
{:c 5}
```

...thus discarding all other keys, including the `:b` branch, which is thus not traversed.

Comment: how do I traverse all of the branches to find all of the :c keys? I thought prewalk would walk the entire form and call the function on every inner form (like the prewalk-demo output)

Comment: this works how I would expect it to: (clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (number? %)(inc %) %) {:a 1 :b [{:c 3} {:d 4}] :c 5})
=> {:a 2, :c 6, :b [{:c 4} {:d 5}]}

Comment: @RobBuhler, yes, but the `inc` version isn't removing any branches; it increments numbers, but leaves everything else alone. The `select-keys` version removes branches outright, so they no longer exist to be traversed.

Comment: thanks, I understand it now. I also found another question to get all of the values for a given key in a nested structure here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332448/how-to-get-all-values-for-a-given-key-in-a-nested-structure-in-clojure